# Undefined en ciclo for - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy haciendo un programa donde encuentro múltiplos de 3 y 5, mientras itero hasta el numero que ingrese por parámetro de la función, a lo ultimo me da undefined, no puedo entender por que:

```js
function multiplo(numero) {

    for(let i=1; i<=numero; i++){

        if(i%3==0 && i%5==0){

         document.write(i+"es multiplo de 3 y 5"+"<br>");

        }else if(i%3==0){

            document.write(i+"es multiplo de 3"+"<br>");

        }else if(i%5==0){

            document.write(i+"es multiplo de 5"+"<br>");

        }else{

             document.write(i+"no es multiplo de 3, ni de 5<br>");
        }   
    }  
}

document.write(multiplo(8));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Multiplos</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Ese error es porque estás llamando a la función con un document.write y la función no tiene un return. Elimina el document.write(multiplo(8)); y pon simplemente multipo(8);

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D , Saludos!